# How to search data timestamp in sql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbPLC.dbo.PLC_CPacking3KW2P3 AS A 
INNER JOIN dbPLC.dbo.PLC_CPacking3KW2P3 AS B ON B.NoUrut = A.NoUrut - 1 
WHERE A.Nilai - B.Nilai = 1 
AND CONVERT(DATE, A.TimeStamp) = CONVERT(DATE, '2017/08/13') 
AND DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(DAY, 1, A.TimeStamp)) BETWEEN 7 AND 15
```

I want to query between 09:00:00 and 10:00:00
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Because of `dbo` i assume you are using SQL Server (MSSQL) and not MySQL. MySQL does not support `DATEPART` and `DATEADD` functions also MySQL does not support `CONVERT(DATE, '2017/08/13')` syntax the correct syntax in MySQL is  `CONVERT('2017/08/13', DATE)` make sure you tag the correct database next time when asking..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
convert(varchar(8),convert(time,A.TimeStamp)) between '09:00:00' and '10:00:00'
```